# How to build an pojo class for a lastfm album.search json response parse

Tags: javascript, android

I have the Json here

http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=album.search&album=the+essence+of+charlie+parker&limit=1&api_key=26980b71e5c813da2c7e0156afdddd4f&format=json

And I made this pojo class to parse it

```
import java.util.List;

public class LastFmAlbumInfo {

    public Results results;

    public class Results {

        QueryInfo queryInfo;
        String totalResults;
        String startIndex;
        String itemsPerPage;
        AlbumMatches albumMatches;
        Attribute attribute;

        public class QueryInfo {
            String text;
            String role;
            String searchTerms;
            String startPage;
        }

        public class AlbumMatches {

            List<Album> albums;

            public class Album {

                String name;
                String artist;
                String url;
                List<Image> images;
                String streamable;
                String mbid;

                public class Image {

                    String imageUrl;
                    String imageSizeDescription;
                }
            }
        }

        public class Attribute {

            String _for;
        }
    }
}
```

When I reference one of the child attributes for example

```
response.results.totalResults
```

I get this error

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.util.List com.example.michael.musicplayer5.LastFmAlbumInfo$Results$AlbumMatches.albums' on a null object reference

I'm not sure what's wrong with my pojo class.

I'm using Volley to make the GET request

```
    String requestUrl = getUrl(albumObject.albumTitle);
    getRequestQueue();
    GsonRequest<LastFmAlbumInfo> myReq = new GsonRequest<>(
            Request.Method.GET,
            requestUrl,
            LastFmAlbumInfo.class,
            null,
            createMyReqSuccessListener(requestUrl, albumObject),
            createMyReqErrorListener(requestUrl));
    mRequestQueue.add(myReq);
```

Comment: Also this mess of nested inner classes is almost certainly not what you want

Comment: Never had any problems with nested inner classes. I nested them so I could model the json response object by hand. Also, I'm not getting a 404 error from Volley in the error response. I'm just getting a null response object.

Comment: Click on the link you've provided, it 404s. Nobody can help you if they can't reproduce what you are trying to do.

Comment: Clearly. The link should be working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.util.List;

public class LastFmAlbumInfo {

    @SerializedName("results")
    public Results results;

    public class Results {

        //@SerializedName(“opensearch:Query”)
        //QueryInfo opensearch;

        @SerializedName("opensearch:totalResults")
        String totalResults;

        @SerializedName("opensearch:startIndex")
        String startIndex;

        @SerializedName("opensearch:itemsPerPage")
        String itemsPerPage;

        @SerializedName("albummatches")
        AlbumMatches albumMatches;

        @SerializedName("@attr")
        Attribute attribute;

        public class QueryInfo {

            @SerializedName("#text")
            String text;

            @SerializedName("role")
            String role;

            @SerializedName("searchTerms")
            String searchTerms;

            @SerializedName("startPage")
            String startPage;
        }

        public class AlbumMatches {

            @SerializedName("album")
            List<Album> albums;

            public class Album {

                @SerializedName("name")
                String name;

                @SerializedName("artist")
                String artist;

                @SerializedName("url")
                String url;

                @SerializedName("image")
                List<Image> images;

                @SerializedName("streamable")
                String streamable;

                @SerializedName("mbid")
                String mbid;

                public class Image {

                    @SerializedName("#text")
                    String imageUrl;

                    @SerializedName("size")
                    String imageSizeDescription;
                }
            }
        }

        public class Attribute {

            @SerializedName("for")
            String _for;
        }
    }
```